# How to protect Object Fields in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

```
O: [a: 1 b: 2]
Protect 'O
```

does only protect O symbol not O/a. How do I also protect O/a ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your example doesn't actually use an object. It's just a block called `O`. So:

```
O: reduce [a: 1 b: 2]
protect [o a b] ; assuming you wanted to protect b as well
```

Now, if you wanted an actual object, you have to do it this way:

```
O: make object! [
    a: 1
    b: 2
    protect [a b]
]
protect 'O
```

R3 will have additional cool things you can do with `PROTECT`, like `PROTECT/HIDE`.